# spliting string in 2 word string set in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to split the string into 2 words string sets. For example,

```
string str = "I want to split the string into 2 words"
```

Output should be like this:

```
1: "I want"
2: "want to"
3: "to split"
4: "split the"
5: "the string"
6: "string into"
7: "into 2"
8: "2 words"
```

What should be the best method to do this?

I tried this way,

```
var pairs = textBox1.Text.Split(' ')
.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
.GroupBy(n => n.i / 2)
.Select(g => string.Join(" ", g.Select(p => p.s)))
.ToList();
```

But its not working. I got the following string sets.

```
1: "I want"
2: "to split"
3: "the string"
4: "into 2"
5: "words"
```

But this is not I am looking for.
 How can I achieve this? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind editing the String or does it have to be as it is. Otherwise you could add a '-' symbol or something and then split it using that? Otherwise a simple for loop will do it where you ignore it every other one.

Comment: Its a dynamic string. So I need to split into 2 set of words list as I mentioned.

Comment: What is considered a word for this task? Anything between spaces?

Comment: Okay @RajDeInno, I'll post the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

How about spliting with white space, iterate until last item and put two item with formatting into that list?

```
string str = "I want to split the string into 2 words";
var array = str.Split(' ');

var list = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
{
     list.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", array[i], array[i + 1]));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as you have done, split each word by space, like so:

```
String[] words = str.Split(' ')
```

Now, simply iterate through this array and concatenate the two pairs of strings each time into a new array.

```
String[] pairs = new String[words.Length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i+1 < words.length; i++)
{
    pairs[i] = string.Format("{0} {1}", words[i], words[i+1]);
}
```

This code might not be syntactically correct, but the idea will work!

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to share a regex approach:

```
var s = "I want to split the string into 2 words";
var result = Regex.Matches(s, @"(\w+)(?=\W+(\w+))")
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(p => string.Format("{0} {1}", p.Groups[1].Value, p.Groups[2].Value))
               .ToList();
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/GBuYxe)

With `(\w+)(?=\W+(\w+))` [regex](https://regex101.com/r/cY2jA7/2), we make sure we capture a word (`(\w+)`) and then capture the next word but do not consume it with a lookahead (`(?=\W+(\w+))`) (using the `(\w+)`) but omitting the non-word characters (`\W+`). Then we just join the 2 words in the `Select`.